# Problem compiling modular_cloud_matcher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was installing modular_cloud_matcher following instructions on this page: [modular_cloud_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/modular_cloud_matcher). However there's an error which is as below:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> libnabo [ make ]                                     
[ rosmake ] All 5 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p build
  cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.. -DPYTHON_CUSTOM_TARGET=src ../upstream_src
  CMake Error: The source directory "/home/wei/ros/ros-mapping/libnabo/upstream_src" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
  Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package libnabo written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/wei/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120514-172456/libnabo/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< libnabo [FAIL] [ 0.05 seconds ]                        
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package libnabo. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 51 packages with 1 failures.
```

Did I do something wrong or I forgot something important? I'm using Electric on Maverick. Thanks for answering!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33936/problem-compiling-modular_cloud_matcher/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if you solved your problem by now but their are now deb packages to install the stack **ethz_icp_mapping** in which the node you're having problem to compile is.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ethzasl-icp-mapping
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ethzasl-icp-mapping
```

There is no support for electric any more.

Also, the node was modular_cloud_matcher was renamed **ethzasl_icp_mapper**.

I hope this help!

---

Originally posted by [Francois](https://answers.ros.org/users/4341/francois/) with karma: 101 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1